# redirecting the execlp output to a file

Tags: c, redirect

How can I redirect the `execlp` output to a file? For example, I want to redirect the output of `execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL)` to an output file(say a.txt).

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `exec*`? Those functions *replace* the current process by the new one.

Comment: Yes, I can create a child process by using a `fork`.

Comment: @miraj: Hm, well, the exec process will inherit the file descriptors of the calling process, so you can use the various `fd*` functions to close and reopen file descriptor 1 (stdout).

Comment: @Kerrek SB : many thanks! Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Miraj: Eric's answer below is much better. I hadn't thought of manipulating the stdout FILE* directly. No need to bother with raw file descriptors. (I was thinking of using `close()` and `openat()`.)

Comment: Actually Eric's answer is the wrong (fragile, unreliable, not sanctioned by standards) way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do something like this:

```
int fd = open("output_file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
dup2(fd, 1);
close(fd);
execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)0);
```

Comment: If the child process does the above part (opening file, closing file and running execlp), can I read that created file from my parent process without any synchronization problem once the child process is terminated.

Comment: Yes. Just `wait` for the child to terminate so you know when it's done writing. Alternatively you could use a `pipe` and read the data as it's generated, without ever storing it to a file - that's usually preferable if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to use freopen to open standard output on a new file:

> FILE *
>       freopen(const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode,
>           FILE *restrict stream);

From the man page for fopen (which includes freopen):

> The freopen() function opens the file
>   whose name is the string pointed
>        to by filename and associates the stream pointed to by stream with it.
>        The original stream (if it exists) is closed.  The mode argument
>   is
>        used just as in the fopen() function.

So, in your case, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *myStdOut;
myStdOut = freopen("a.txt", "rw", stdout);
if (myStdOut == NULL)
    // Error case, open failed
```

The particulars may vary from OS to OS and compiler versions.

Comment: `freopen` is not the right tool for this. It's not even guaranteed to use the same file descriptor number, and should basically never be used in POSIX programs.

Comment: And by never in POSIX programs, I mean never in programs which use POSIX features outside the bare ANSI/ISO C, i.e. it's okay to use `freopen` to redirect `stdout` purely within your own process that just uses `stdio` for output, but not if you're mixing file descriptor io or inheritance of file descriptors between processes and new program images.